# Critical error installing Ubuntu 20.04.06

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, system-installation, 22.04

I am getting the following error while trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.06 from a usb drive.

Running dpkg

```
(Skip)
(ubiquity: 2233): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:55:58.933: gtk box gadget distribute: assertion "size se 0' failed in GtkScrollbar (ubiquity: 2233): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:56:02.149: gtk box gadget_distribute: assertion 'size s= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar (ubiquity:2233): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:56:06.181: gtk box gadget_distribute: assertion 'size s= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar
XDG RUNTIME DIR (run/user /999) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 999! (This could e.g. happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulsesA
udio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
```

I just aborted the install and the computer was able to boot successfully. Could my system be broken or would it be fine? If I upgrade the system to  22.04 would it fix any potential issues on the 20.04 install during the upgrade

Comment: GTK-Critical should not stop the installation. But I'd advise you to install 22.04, since that will be supported longer than 20.04

Comment: Are you sure the error message is as you quoted?  It has mismatched quotes & other minor *glitches*...  Did the media verification succeed?  If it didn't, I'd not trust the installed as where there are *installation media* issues, the errors can be unusual or unexpected as the installation isn't to be trusted.  I'm not familiar with the message, but I'd validate your media for starters.

Comment: Media was verified. All okay. The error repeats The XDG RUNTIME DIR is the main issue. I took a picture of the errors and typed them in as there was  to copy them as is